# Weird Laravel Auth Attempt Always Return False

Tags: laravel-6

I encountered this annoying error when using custom LoginController, where the Auth::attempt always return false. I tried every solutions posted online but nothing works, any idea whats happening in this Laravel6 application ?

```
 public function authenticate(Request $request) .......
    $ubersmith = ///external api call to get email
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $ubersmith->data->email, 'password' => $request->input('password')])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        var_dump('login');
        return redirect('/');
    }
    $user = \App\User::create([
        'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password')),
        'email' => $ubersmith->data->email,
        'name' => $ubersmith->data->fullname
    ]);
    Auth::login($user);
    var_dump($user);
    return redirect('/2');
}
```

Comment: Where did you declare the `$ubersmith` variable?

Comment: its on the above, inside function. The email came from external Api.email and passwords are all correct, just wondering why this Auth::attempt always return false

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the correct params to the `Auth:attempt`. You can do basic debugging, try doing `dd($ubersmith->data->email);` and `dd($request->input('password'));`

Comment: I am really sure I am passing correct params

Comment: I also noticed it generate different hashed password for the same password

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong with the code. Are you sure the user is already in your database? You can try `dd(Auth::attempt(['email' => $ubersmith->data->email, 'password' => $request->input('password')]));`. Does it really returns false?

Comment: Laravel uses brypt to hash password, the hash generated for the same password will be different. Laravel automatically has a way to check the correct password using the `Auth::attempt` method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206897/discussion-between-aceraven777-and-ira).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, seems that there's nothing wrong with it. You can try debugging it, e.g. putting `dd($ubersmith->data->email);` and `dd($request->input('password'));` to check if you're passing the correct data.

Another possibility is you're putting the incorrect password. Can you try doing:

```
dd(Hash::make($request->input('password')));
```

Then update your password using this value, then try to authenticate again.

Comment: Manually adding hashed password to database make Auth::attempt work, how ever creating a new user and encrypting password using Hash::make will make Auth::attempt return false everytime a user logged in even though its already in db

Comment: Really? Can you try creating a new user using `Hash::make` then logging in again?

Comment: Will the problem is in user creation. I just updated the code,saving the password plainly meaning without hashing, so 'password' => $request->input('password') and it works. Seems not in Laravel 6 docs but thats how to make it working, anyway I will mark your answer as accepted since you correctly pointed out where the error comes

Comment: Oh, that's weird, maybe you did something in your `User` model so when you create a user it will automatically hash the password for you. Anyway, glad to help.

Comment: nope.this is a fresh install of laravel and I only touch the controller part